# How to extract a string from html body content and add as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use javascript to extract 1234 from the html body below and add this 1234 as a javascript variable. I will be adding this script into multiple html pages with a mixture of text, images, etc. However, the links are all the same except for the id part which will change with each page. There will be duplicates of the same links on a page, but I only need to add one instance of the id 1234 as a javascript variable. Thank you for your help.

Example of basic HTML

```
  <html>
<body>
blah blah <p>
<a href="https://example.com/tracking.php?id=1234">example link</a>
<p>
more blah blah <a href="https://example.com/tracking.php?id=1234">duplicate link</a>
<p>
even more blah blah
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far? Please edit all the pertinent information regarding the attempts you’ve made, along with a succinct explanation of where *specifically* in your attempts you’re getting stuck in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that brings you a solution.

```
function getparams(param, elID) {
  const href = document.getElementById(elID).getAttribute('href');
  const params = href.split("?")[1];
  const allParams = params.split('&'), paramName, i;
  for (i = 0; i < allParams.length; i++) {
    paramName = allParams[i].split('=');
    if (paramName[0] === param) {
      return paramName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURI(paramName[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
function getparams(param, elID) {
  let href = document.getElementById(elID).getAttribute('href');
  let params = href.split("?")[1];
  let allParams = params.split('&'), paramName, i;
  for (i = 0; i < allParams.length; i++) {
    paramName = allParams[i].split('=');
    if (paramName[0] === param) {
      return paramName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURI(paramName[1]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(getparams("id", "myLink"))
console.log(getparams("anyParam", "myLink"))
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href="https://example.com/tracking.php?id=1234&anyParam=124000">example link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I appreciate it!

Comment: @leon-tran Great, If your issue is resolved then I invite you to accept my answer, and if it was helpful (sounds like it was) then please also remember to upvote it as well (if you haven't already). Cheers